# server side push (comete) to populate full Calendar event without javascript polling in Grails.

Tags: grails, fullcalendar, server-push, reverse-ajax

anybody can please, tell me how we can populate /display data updated dynamically at server side on full calendar without javascript polling /setInterval. there is Atmosphere plugin given in grails but documentation is very poor.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket technology provides full-duplex communications via an upgraded HTTP connection. Both the client and the server need to (over)write 3 methods: @OnOpen, @OnMessage and @OnClose. Try this:

http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2014/12/07/using-websockets-in-grails/